# How to log in and auto fill values into a 'drupal form' from an 'excel file'?

Tags: excel, drupal, autofill

So, there is this website where I have to log in and insert values in the *add content->person roles* and I have to take values from an excel file. I tried entering the values in the database directly but got nowhere. The database is too randomly generated.

I want to know- how to go by this problem? I think *python* would be the best way but I am more comfortable with *java*. The images bellow will help understand the situation better-

The log in from:
[image: log in form]

The form to be filled:
[image: log in form]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using feeds module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds

Install it on you site first of course. Or look for some similar import module. Maybe this one:

https://www.drupal.org/project/datasources

If nothing succeeds then try making import script on your own. You have to parse document (would be much easier to open it from excel and export as CSV if possible http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) and have some loop to write content into Drupal system. Use Drupal's functions for that, do not directly write to database. It's not hard as it looks like:

https://www.drupal.org/node/1388922

Comment: this was THE solution .. successfully made the transfer ... cheers

Comment: hmm now ive tried the feeds module and that does work but the values inserted doest come up when checked from other content types, is there a way where i can log in and do these things form the front end ? like a java parsing script ??